# What all possible times 'kazoo.exceptions.ConnectionLoss' is raised?

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I am using `apache-zookeeper` and `kazoo framework` for one of my requirement. I have a simple zookeeper cluster setup and few clients connecting to server cluster to read node information. I am facing `kazoo.exceptions.ConnectionLoss` randomly(once in fifty times).
My concern is on what all times this exception is raised ? Below are the points I thought.

- Connection to server was lost
- Server didn't respond back within timeout set in server configuration

Can there be any other reasons for this exception? I don't see documentation explaining anything in detail on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear I don't have ready answer but looking at Kazoo code I think this can come in following conditions,

- Socket read timeout,
- Socket write timeout,
- deserialize failure because of timeout issues,
- Client creation with high initial bytes value of node

Tried to gather this from [Kazoo](https://github.com/python-zk/kazoo/tree/c85969a4809b0d6be270ae6791b31ee4676c2c62/kazoo) unittest code [test_connection](https://github.com/python-zk/kazoo/blob/c85969a4809b0d6be270ae6791b31ee4676c2c62/kazoo/tests/test_connection.py) [test_client](https://github.com/python-zk/kazoo/blob/b4967d16b3daa4b1a00c0f408888b4f61e5486cc/kazoo/tests/test_client.py) ,